# React testing child component based on side effect

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have a component in  Component.js, where banner is another component. How could I test it for different count ? I tried to test it with [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro), but the child component was not updating. Useeffect is not working with [enzyme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme) also

```
   const [newCount, setCounter] = useState(0);
     useEffect(() => {
        const counter = getCounterValue('counter1');
        setCounter(counter);
    });
    labels = {title : 'hello', description: 'there', title_v1 : 'Hi',description_v1: 'World' };
    switch (newCount) {
        case 1:
            labels.description = labels.description_v1;
            labels.title = labels.title_v1;
            break;
        case 2:
            labels.description = '';
            labels.title = labels.title_v1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return (<Banner  {...labels}/>);
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the full code for Component and for the Banner component. react-testing-library is designed to test the DOM nodes and not implementation details, i.e. you should not have to worry about useEffect implementation.

Comment: I want to test the banner component on different newCount.